how to 3d render with only drawing pixels
I have been trying to find ways to display a 3d scene on a screen (specifically 480x240px Vex robotics brain). The only ways that I can draw to the screen is with drawing individual pixels or with drawing rectangles/circles. What are my options for drawing methods to the screen. I have tried my own awkward way of raycasting/raymarching but that has turned out poorly. I also want to have everything in a camera of sorts that can be moved around in the 3d world. I do not have any options to use frameworks such as opengl or directx.
If it is not clear, I want to create a program in c++ that can display 3d graphics sort of like doom and wolfenstein does it where the player can walk around in a 3d world.

Hi , there's a nice video of someone implementing a doom style engine in C++ for console.
Some of this might be applicable to your case.

Also, and this is just me being a pedant, but Dooms graphic engine is a lot more advanced than that of Wolfenstein 3d

here is a link to a guy's play list where he does just that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ih20l3pJoeU

Thanks for the help Knogger and yosmo78, those videos and that guy explaining it helped me get my own program woking.
